# glassfish server not shown in server wizard

Tags: glassfish

I have installed glassfish3.1 in ubuntu. while adding glassfish to the eclipse from file->new->other->server , the list is showing tomcat version but not glassfish. glassfish is running on localhost:4848. I also have installed apache2 for php-mysql. Is it creating the error? help me please.

Comment: Have you installed the Glassfish Server Tools?

Comment: I installed glassfish through marketplace option in eclipse